# WP All Import Issues

Tags: plugins, wordpress

I am using WP All Import plugin to import real estate properties. I got an error when updating the properties.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Undefined
>   field type.' in
>   /public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-all-import/models/model/record.php:148
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-all-import/controllers/admin/import.php(1764):
>   PMXI_Model_Record->__get('type') #1
>   /public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-all-import/plugin.php(348):
>   PMXI_Admin_Import->process() #2
>   /public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-all-import/plugin.php(282):
>   PMXI_Plugin->adminDispatcher('pmxi-admin-impo...', 'process') #3
>   [internal function]: PMXI_Plugin->__adminInit('') #4
>   /public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(470): call_user_func_array(Array,
>   Array) #5 /public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(144):
>   do_action('admin_init') #6 {main} thrown in
>   /public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-all-import/models/model/record.php
>   on line 148

May i know, how to fix it?

Comment: download the latest version or check or plugin compatibility with your current theme  or update your theme if required

Comment: after updating wordpress theme, it happens.

Comment: have plugin require updation ?

Comment: also check  it may required data base update

Comment: that is free version. i downloaded it.